# How to find the installed version of a package using yarn classic?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I've this dependency in my `package.json`:

```
"@babel/core": "7.13.13"
```

I check this is the installed version:

```
yarn list --depth 0 --pattern @babel/core
yarn list v1.22.19
└─ @babel/core@7.13.13
```

Now I manually update my `package.json` to:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.13.13"
```

I **do not** run `install` or `upgrade`, I just check the "installed" version again:

```
yarn list v1.22.19
└─ @babel/core@7.24.0
```

Why it changed to `7.24.0`? `yarn.lock` still shows `"@babel/core@7.13.13"` and if I `cat node_modules/@babel/core/package.json` I can still see version `7.13.13` installed.

If I list without `--depth 0` I can confirm no other dependency is using version `7.24.0`.

Also tried using `yarn why` but I found the same issue.

What am I missing?